# How to turn an ArrayList of a class into a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to change my ArrayLists into HashMaps. Below is the code I have which takes a food item and returns its price. I have an ArrayList of Restaurants, menuList. A Restaurant class contains a menu, currently also an ArrayList. I want to perform a lookup for a foodItem string, which may be in any restaurant(and exists and is unique to that restaurant). I believe its best that menu is a HashMap, how would a HashMap menu look containing Menu types? Would it be best that I store a HashMap of Restaurant's too, rather than an ArrayList? How would my lookup then differ?

**Restaurant class:**

```
public class Restaurant {

    String name;
    String location;
    ArrayList<Menu> menu;

    public int getCost(String foodItem) {

            for (Menu item : menu) {
                if (item.item.equals(foodItem)) {
                    return item.pence;
                }
            }
        return 0;
    }

}
```

**Menu class:**

```
public class Menu {
    String item;
    int cost;
}
```

**Method elsewhere to return cost:**

```
for (Restaurant i : menuList) {  
                for (Menu items : i.menu) { 
                        if (Objects.equals(items.item, foodItem))
                            cost += i.getCost(foodItem);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Refactor the "Menu" class to "Item" class and generate getters and setters;

```
public class Item {
String name;
int cost;   
}
```

so on your "Restaurant" class you don't need to declare the getCost() and declare:

```
ArrayList<Item> menu;
```

what makes more sense, because a menu is a list of items, and all you have to call is:

```
for (Item item : menu) { 
    if (Objects.equals(item.getName(), foodItem))
                        cost += item.getCost();
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Going with the suggestion to rename `Menu` to the more clear `Item` it could look something like this:

```
public class Restaurant {

    String name;
    String location;
    Map<String, Item> menu = new HashMap<>();

    public Collection<Item> getMenu() {
        menu.values();
    }

    public int getCost(String foodItem) {
        Item item = menu.get(food item);
        return item == null ? 0 : item.getCost();
    }
}
```

Should you do the same for your `List<Restaurant>`? It depends. If you only use it for looking for a restaurant yes, but generally you want to prefer `List` or `Set` over `Map`. Right now the only purpose of menu is to be used to search for a Item and you are designing you're class for only that purpose. If you ever need the same class for something else you now have a `Map` that is specialized for searching with a key, but for example not optimized for Looping through every menu item.

Comment: Pointless to repeat the name of the item in Item. Why not just `Map<String, Integer> costs`.